# When trying to start VLC using the child process using the telegram bot command, an error appears

Tags: node.js, child-process, telegraf

```
const ChildProcess = require("child_process");
const { Telegraf, Extra, Markup, Stage, session, Scenes, Composer } = require('telegraf');

const BOT_TOKEN = "***";
const bot = new Telegraf(BOT_TOKEN, {
    telegram: {webhookreply: true},
});

bot.hears('start', (ctx) => {
    startVLC()
})

async function startVLC(){
    process = ChildProcess.exec(`"C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe" --loop --playlist-cork  "C:\\PLAYLIST\\testplaylist.xspf"`, async function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (error) {
            console.error(`exec error: ${error}, ${stderr}`);
        }else{
          console.log(stdout);
        }
    });
}
```

an error appears

```
ERROR
[nodemon] starting `node ./index.js`

C:\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1521
                if (parseInt(process.version.substring(1)) < 14) {
                                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substring')
    at C:\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1521:32
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at fetch (C:\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1447:9)
    at Telegram.callApi (C:\node_modules\telegraf\lib\core\network\client.js:291:52)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async [Symbol.asyncIterator] (C:\node_modules\telegraf\lib\core\network\polling.js:30:33)
    at async Polling.loop (C:\node_modules\telegraf\lib\core\network\polling.js:73:30)
    at async Telegraf.launch (C:\node_modules\telegraf\lib\telegraf.js:189:13)
```

Node.js v18.12.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

if you run only the function without the bot, then everything works without errors